# Programatically move or copy Google Drive file to a shared Windows folder/UNC

Tags: excel

I have a Google Apps Script that builds a new csv file any time someone makes an edit to one of our shared google sheets (via a trigger). The file gets saved off to a dedicated Shared Drive folder (which is first cleaned out by trashing all existing files before writing the updated one). This part works splendidly.

I need to take that CSV and consume it in SSIS so I can datestamp it and load it into a MSSQL table for historical tracking purposes, but aside from paying for some third-party apps (i.e. CDATA, COZYROC), I can't find a way to do this. Eventually this package will be deployed on our SQL Agent to run on a daily schedule, so it will be attached to a service account that wouldn't have any sort of access to the Google Shared drive. If I can get that CSV over to one of the shared folders on our SQL server, I will be golden...but that is what I am struggling with.

If something via Apps Script isn't possible, is there someone that can direct me as to how I might then be able to programmatically get an Excel spreadsheet to open, refresh its dataset, then save itself and close? I can get the data I need into Excel out of the Google Sheet directly using a Power Query, but need it to refresh itself in an unattended process on a daily schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I found that CData actually has a tool called Sync which got us what we needed out of this. There is a limited-options free version of the tool (that they claim it's "free forever") that runs as a local service. On a set schedule, it can query all sorts of sources, including Google Sheets, and will write out to various destinations.

The free version has limited availability in terms of the sources and destinations you can use (though there are quite a few), but it only allows 2 connection definitions. That said, you can define multiple source files, but only 1 source type (i.e. I can define 20 different Google Sheets to use in 20 different jobs, but can only use Google Sheets as my source).

I have it setup to read my shared google sheet and output the CSV to our server's share. A  SSIS project reads the local CSV, processes it as needed, and then writes to our SQL server. Seems to work pretty well if you don't mind having an additional service running, and don't need a series of different sources and destinations.

Link to their Sync landing page: https://www.cdata.com/sync/

Use the Buy Now button and load up the free version in your cart, then proceed to check out. They will email you a key and a link to get the download from.